# Differentiable path with constant norm implies circle?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval
and let $\gamma :I \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable path.
Given that 
$\|\gamma (t) \| = 1$, $\forall \, t \in I$,
fix a point $t_0 \in I$ and denote:
$\gamma ( t_0 ) =: \vec{a}$,  $\gamma'( t_0 ) =: \vec{q}$. 
I want to prove that$\langle \, \vec{a} \, , \, \vec{q} \, \rangle = 0$).

I understand intuitively that the path must describe the unit circle. But to prove this generally doesn't seem that simple. One idea would be to somehow generally parametrize this path, but is this actually possible at all? That is, if we think about polar coordinates, can we just say that $(x,y)=(r\cos(t), r\sin(t))$, such that $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{r\cos^2(t)+r\sin^2(t)}=1$, and then we deduce that $r=1$?

Also, it is given that $I$ is an open interval. But does it matter in this case that it is open and not closed?

Comment: The path must not be a circle in general. It is quite possible a curve in a sphere. But if the torsion vanishes, then it's a circle. Finally $r=1$ is correct if $m=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result follows from
$$\frac{d}{dt}\lVert{\gamma(t)}\rVert^2=2\langle\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\rangle=0$$
Differentiability is only defined on open sets.

Comment: Differentiability on a closed interval is often defined.

Comment: Of course, when the one sided limits exists